# $\exp\left({\frac{-1}{(x-a)(b-x)}}\right) $ is infinitely differentiable on $(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $a<b$. I'm trying to prove that $$\exp\left({\frac{-1}{(x-a)(b-x)}}\right) $$ is infinitely differentiable in the open interval $(a,b)$. Induction seems like a good way to proceed, and I know that $\exp(-1/x)$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere except at $x = 0$. But I'm not sure if this helps me in the proof. Any clues on how to proceed?

Comment: Composition of differentiable functions is differentiable

Answer (score 0):

Make $y=(x-a)(b-x)$, then your function trasforms to $exp(-\frac{1}{y})$ and it's infinitely differentiable except points where $y = 0$, e.g. $x = a$ or $x=b$. But $a$ and $b$ aren't included in interval $(a,b)$ so your function is infinitely differentiable.